# Create a custom report in MVC4?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have not to much experience in `Reporting` in `MVC4`. I'm looking for a way to generate a report, this one is not common, I mean, I need to generate a report something like this one

[image]

As you can see, contains so much static text, and gets some parameter like the name, id, date, and an array of current grades of a students in a vertical text.

I've search for that, but I only found list reports. Can you orient me which components do I need to generate this report as printable (PDF for example)?

Answer (score 2):

If you think of this as a very short list with many columns, the examples you've found may work OK.

But if I were in your position, I would probably use SQL server reporting services (SSRS) to generate a PDF-report.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965699.aspx

Comment: just confirming, is this one? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2013/03/06/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2012-released-online.aspx I have no idea about SSRS